# Manage a big file thanks to text-processing with AWK or a script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

To answer to @Ed Morton,

***Inputs***

```
...
useless_words Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 452 useless_words
useless_words Number_100 : Rename message (old 452 ; new 557)
useless_words Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 557 useless_words
useless_words Number_101 : Message xx Toronto xx Rio useless_words -Code 842 useless_words
useless_words Number_102 : Message xx Rome xx Moscow useless_words -Code 432 useless_words
useless_words Number_103 : Message from Dublin to Paris -Code 557
useless_words Number_103 : Error Message
...
useless_words Number_110 : Message xx Alger xx Barcelona useless_words -Code 345 useless_words
useless_words Number_110 : Rename message (old 345 ; new 846)
useless_words Number_110 : Message xx Alger xx Barcelona useless_words -Code 846 useless_words
useless_words Number_111 : Message xx Mexico xx Dallas useless_words -Code 498 useless_words
useless_words Number_112 : Rename message (old 432 ; new 245)
...
useless_words Number_115 : Message from Alger to Barcelona -Code 846
useless_words Number_115 : Error Message
...
```

***Outputs***

```
useless_words Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 452 useless_words
useless_words Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 557 useless_words
useless_words Number_100 : Message from Dublin to Paris -Code 557
useless_words Number_110 : Message xx Alger xx Barcelona useless_words -Code 345 useless_words
useless_words Number_110 : Message xx Alger xx Barcelona useless_words -Code 846 useless_words
useless_words Number_110 : Message from Alger to Barcelona -Code 846
```

In order to do that, I thought to follow these steps.

- 1. I match a line containing Error Message => I get the message number (Number_103 and Number_115 here)
- 2. I search for a line with the number (Number_103 and Number_115) and I pick 3 words (for this example $6 $8 $10 => Dublin Paris 557; Alger Barcelona 846). I print the line. I get my first message.
- 3. I search for a line which matches these 3 words and I note the message number (Number_100 and Number_110 here). I print this line. I get my second message.
- 4. I search for the rename message which has the same message number as the last message printed (Number_100 and Number_110 here) and I get the old key (345 and 452 here)
- 5. I search for the last message to print thanks to the old key (345 and 452 here) and the message number (Number_100 and Number_110 here)
- 6. I modify the message number of the first message printed (Number_103 -> Number_100; Number_115 -> Number_110)

I wrote that

```
#!bin/bash
            
    grep -B1 'Error' inputs.txt |sed '/^-/d' | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v Error >> tmp_01.txt
    
    while read line
    do  
    
    read a b c <<< $(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f6,8,10)
    
    awk -v a1="$a" -v a2="$b" -v a3="$c" '$0~a1 && $0~a2 && $0~a3' inputs.txt >> tmp_02.txt
    
    done < tmp_01.txt
    
    awk '{++i} i==1 {a=$2} i==2 {$2=a; i=0} 1' tmp_02.txt
    
    rm -f tmp_*.txt
```

I get that

```
useless_words Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 557 useless_words
useless_words Number_100 : Message from Dublin to Paris -Code 557
useless_words Number_110 : Message xx Alger xx Barcelona useless_words -Code 846 useless_words
useless_words Number_110 : Message from Alger to Barcelona -Code 846
```

I try to get a quick code, thank you to Bodo for his help !

In real, I have one message sent to a BOX which is sent to an other place (They have the same Number_).

```
useless_words Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 452 useless_words

useless_words Number_100 : Rename message (old 452 ; new 557)

useless_words Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 557 useless_words
```

Then, I have an ACK sent until the BOX (with a different Number_).

```
useless_words Number_103 : Message from Dublin to Paris -Code 557
```

Normally, this ACK received by the BOX is sent to an other BOX but, sometimes, this ACK is blocked, which is the case when I receive the Error message.

```
useless_words Number_103 : Error Message
```

Comment: In terms of magnitude, how big is "a big file of data"? #1 What defines an error message line? #2 Do you always pick items $6, $8, $10? If not, what are your criteria for selecting fields? #3
Do they have to match consecutively and in order, or just anywhere in the line? #4 Search just forwards, or backwards too?

Comment: My file has more than 100000 lines and 2500 error messages. #1 The term "Error" is what define an error message line.  #2 Yes  #3 They have to match consecutively and in order. #4 When an error message is found, the messages to print are all the time above. I am sorry, I am not an English speaker. It's not a real-time file.

Comment: I wanted to use grep like that, cat file.txt | grep Error | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs -I {} ... but this kind of program need a lot of computer capabilities. So I would like to use awk because it's more efficient but I don't know to use it.

Comment: No need for `cat`. And which of those AWKs are `awk`?

Comment: Can you distinguish possibly interesting messages like `Number_100` from useless messages like `Number_101` based on their content, e.g. useless messages will never contain `-Code` followed by a number and/or never contain `Message` or `Rename message` or `Error Message` after `Number_X :`? Will a message like `Number_103 : Error Message` always appear before the next group of messages like `Number_110`? To answer this, please** [edit] your question**, don't answer in comments.

Comment: My question was not meant to ask about the ascending numbers in the second field, but if a message **like** `Number_103 : Error Message` with any number will always precede the next message **like** `Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 452` (with any numbers) or if two corresponding groups of messages could be interleaved, e.g. `Number_105` instead of `Number_103` and `Number_104` instead of `Number_110`.

Comment: Now your example input shows that the "useless lines" have the same format like the possibly interesting lines which makes the solution more difficult. Another question to avoid problems with the real input: Is `useless_words` a single word as in the example or can it be more than one word? It might be better to show a piece of your real input instead of a manually modified version.

Comment: Is the ascending order of the `Number_X` fields automatically generated or did you use a separate sorting step to create this order? In case you used a separate sorting step, can you sort the file in descending order? This would make it easier to extract the requested lines because the `Error message` line would appear before the corresponding lines that should pe printed.

Comment: Is there any way to detect if a line is interesting or useless before finding the corresponding `Error Message` line? In your modified example the interesting lines appear in groups of 3 lines with the same `Number_X` (`Number_100`, `Number_110`) while the "useless messages" are single messages (`Number_101`, `Number_102`, `Number_111`, `Number_112`) Is this true for your real input?

Comment: @titofpoule Thanks for the additional explanation. The script in the question does not print the expected output. Is this a mistake or a problem you need help with? (There seems to be a typo in the first line your script.)

Comment: @Bodo  My problem is to make things quickly. Until now, with my script, the time processing is not good. I would like to do the same things as my script without the while loop use. Then I will try to add the last message.

Comment: Your sample output differs from your sample input in many ways not described by the text. Are you supposed to copy everything through without change, apart from Rename messages which you haven't described, and messages which later have an error?

Comment: I have explained the main of the Rename messages in my initial post. I agree with you when you say that my sample output differs from my sample input because I need to modify the column 2 for the message just above the Error message. I've explained that in my initial post also. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the modified question and in comments, this answer is an attempt to create a faster script that produces the same result as the script in the question without fixing other problems.

The proposed scripts will process the input file only twice independent from the number of error messages.

**But** I'm not sure this is a better base for modifications to get the output shown in the question. (There is a rule "First make it work than make it fast, not the other way round.")

```
grep -B1 'Error' file.txt |sed '/^-/d' | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v Error| awk '{printf "/%s/ && /%s/ && /%s/\n", $6, $8, $10}' > filter.awk
awk -f filter.awk file.txt
```

or without writing the `awk` script to a file

```
awk -f <(grep -B1 'Error' file.txt |sed '/^-/d' | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v Error| awk '{printf "/%s/ && /%s/ && /%s/\n", $6, $8, $10}') file.txt
```

or without using `grep` (and without any equivalent of the `sed` commands which don't seem to be necessary with the example input)

```
awk -f <(awk '/Error/ && prev {$0=prev;printf "/%s/ && /%s/ && /%s/\n", $6, $8, $10;next} {prev=$0}' file.txt) file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**The solution here does no longer work after the example input in the question has been changed.** Clarification is needed.

The specification of the input format is not clear.

With the original example input from the question, this script prints the expected output.

```
awk '/Number_[0-9]* : Message .* -Code [0-9]* ./ { if($2 != first) i=0; line[i++]=$0; first=$2;}
/Number_[0-9]* : Message from .* -Code [0-9]*$/ { second=$2; sub(second,first); line[i++]=$0}
/Number_[0-9]* : Error Message/ && (second==$2) { print line[0]; print line[1]; print line[2];}' input
```

The script distinguishes the first and second case by expecting a space and any character after the number that follows `-Code` in the first case and the number at the end of the line in the second case.

The original input was

```
...
useless_words Number_98 : useless message
useless_words Number_99 : useless message
useless_words Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 452 useless_words
useless_words Number_100 : Rename message (old 452 ; new 557)
useless_words Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 557 useless_words
useless_words Number_101 : useless message
useless_words Number_102 : useless message
useless_words Number_103 : Message from Dublin to Paris -Code 557
useless_words Number_103 : Error Message
...
useless_words Number_110 : Message xx Alger xx Barcelona useless_words -Code 345 useless_words
useless_words Number_110 : Rename message (old 345 ; new 846)
useless_words Number_110 : Message xx Alger xx Barcelona useless_words -Code 846 useless_words
useless_words Number_111 : useless message
...
useless_words Number_115 : Message from Alger to Barcelona -Code 846
useless_words Number_115 : Error Message
...
```

Output

```
useless_words Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 452 useless_words
useless_words Number_100 : Message xx Dublin xx Paris useless_words -Code 557 useless_words
useless_words Number_100 : Message from Dublin to Paris -Code 557
useless_words Number_110 : Message xx Alger xx Barcelona useless_words -Code 345 useless_words
useless_words Number_110 : Message xx Alger xx Barcelona useless_words -Code 846 useless_words
useless_words Number_110 : Message from Alger to Barcelona -Code 846
```

**Edit after the question has been modified**

The script no longer works with the modified input because the "useless lines" now have the same format like the possibly interesting lines.

To fix this script, either a criteria is needed to distinguish between possibly interesting lines and useless lines, or the script would have to store more than one group of lines until a line with `Error Message` is found.

I asked for clarification of the question.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response. As i have understood that my specification were not  clear enough (I am sorry for my bad english), I have modified the inputs by replacing two useless messages by two relevant messages. As a result of that, I don't know why but the first part of your solution doesn't work.

Comment: @titofpoule: I'm pretty sure that the "useless words" part throw off the parsing (the parsing expect the 2nd word to be relevant ($2))

Comment: @Bodo: to help your parsing (and not depend on an exact positionning) you may want to "sed" first the relevant elements and add before & after each one a specific char, and use that char as a separator in awk : ex:  ".... useless words ... |number_100| : Message xx |Dublin| xx |Paris| useless words here -Code |452| ....." , by judicious usage of sed. Then : awk -F'|' '{ #here you have $2, $4, $6 and $8 correctly refering to the infos you need}'

Comment: @OlivierDulac My script is based on the information in the question where the original script extracted specific fields using `cut`. If any preprocessing is required, this can probably be done in `awk` as well.

Comment: @Bodo, I don't agree. I have explained the problem by saying the steps to follow (since I erased this part).  According to me, it's a need to begin with the error message. I changed the inputs to be clearer but since the beginning it's was the point.

Comment: @titofpoule What exactly don't you agree with? With my impression that the specification of the input data is not clear enough to develop a better/faster algorithm? In this case you might consider the fact that nobody else has written an answer.

Comment: The problem is not easy. So I did my best to explain but it's not easy. I am not an english speaker but thanks to your help I have been improved my level in awk.

Comment: I suspect the problem is fairly easy but I can't figure out what the problem is from your question and it's not about ability to speak English.. Please try to  clarify your question to simply say "here's sample input", "here's the output I expect given that input" and "here are the rules for mapping that input to that output".